# MATLAB: Numerical integration of discontinuous ODE

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I'm working on the numerical integration to a discontinuous ODE in MATLAB, but I'm not getting the results I intended to get.
I have a 2-dof system of two masses connected via springs. (see [2-dof system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeHTT.png))

My function in MATLAB is of the form:

```
function [ xdot ] = two_springs(t, x, m1, m2, c, g, k)
% x(1) = x1
% x(2) = x1'
% x(3) = x2
% x(4) = x2'
delta = max(x(3,1) - x(1,1), 0); % (Discontinuous)
F = k * delta^(3 / 2);
xdot(1,1) = x(2,1);
xdot(2,1) = (-F + m1 * g) / m1;
xdot(3,1) = x(4,1);
xdot(4,1) = (F - c * x(3,1) + m2 * g) / m2;
end
```

Afterwards I plot force F over time.

But no matter which solver I use ( ode45, ode23, ode113, ode15s, ode23s,...) I get a failure because the step size was reduced below the smallest value allowed.
The topic: [MATLAB- ode solver: Unable to meet integration tolerances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273756/matlab-ode-solver-unable-to-meet-integration-tolerances) did unfortunately not help me.

Does anyone have an idea what else I could try?

Thank you very much for your help!
tine-lore

Comment: ODEs by their very nature assume a certain degree of continuity. Inserting a discontinuity will result in a [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation) system that can be difficult to integrate numerically and even lead to errors like you have. Instead, you should simulate the two cases and use [event detection](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html) to switch between them. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13755352/2278029) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22819748/2278029).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at that!

Comment: Your function is continuous, just not differentiable. The maximum of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: What can you say about the part of the solution that it does compute? What kind of singularity do you observe at the break-point?